# Can I mix up plural with singular to resolve pronoun ambiguity?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, antecedents

I have here a sentence with an ambiguous antecedent.

> Computers have larger screens than smartphones, the reason why they are still necessary.

The pronoun "they" can refer back to "*computers*", "*screens*" or "*smartphones*".
Is it possible to resolve this ambiguity by mixing up plurals and singulars?

> Computers have a larger screen than the smartphone, the reason why they are still necessary.

Or can't I avoid to restructure the complete sentence?

> The reason why computers are still necessary is that they have larger screens than smartphones.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is a dangling modifier. It has nothing to do with plural or singular.  Dangling modifiers feel awkward because they do not attach to anything.  Most people will understand you, but in a pinch, you should rewrite it.

Right now, the sentence has "Computers" as subject "larger screen" as object. "The smartphones" is modifying "the screen." "The reason" is the dangling modifier.

I think what you were trying to do is have "Computers be necessary" and everything else modifying that idea. That would be more like:

Since smartphone screens are small, Computers are still necessary.

Something like that.
But not precisely sure if this is your context. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment Mari-Lou wrote:

> ....than smartphones, and **for this reason** they **remain** necessary.

And in another comment, Shoe wrote:

> The theme or topic of the original sentence is *computers* (having larger screens than smartphones). The *reason* clause is a supplement. The theme of the restructured sentence is *the reason why computers are still necessary* (followed by the identification of the reason). So the restructuring changes more than just word order. I agree with @Mari-Lou's suggestion, which sticks more closely to the original meaning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment

Comment: Thank you for removing *reason...why*.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea where to find supporting references, but I'd say that it is at best poor style to mix generic reference styles like this.

You *could* define the (complete!) which-clause more clearly:

- Computers have larger screens than smartphones, which is the reason why computers are still necessary.

But far smoother (if less punchy) is your

- The reason why computers are still necessary is that they have larger screens than smartphones.